# Android - How to use methods from another class in setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, class, button, methods, listener

My code below crashes as soon as I start the app. I want to use my "greenBackground" and "whiteBackground" methods from Methods.class in TestActivity's setOnClickListener methods. Is there a proper way to call the methods from Methods class? Any help is appreciated.

**TestActivity.class:**

```
package com.mfg.test;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Methods method = new Methods();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.program);

        Button greenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GreenButton);
        Button whiteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WhiteButton);

        greenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                method.greenBackground(v);
            }
        });

        whiteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                method.whiteBackground(v);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Methods.class:**

```
package com.mfg.test;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

public class Methods extends TestActivity {

    View rl = findViewById(R.id.rl);

    public void greenBackground(View rl)
    {
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    public void whiteBackground(View rl)
    {
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

**Here is the log file:**

```
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017): Process: com.mfg.test, PID: 2017
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017): java.lang.StackOverflowError
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.<init>(FinalizerReference.java:42)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:54)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker.<init>(StrictMode.java:2244)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.os.StrictMode.trackActivity(StrictMode.java:1946)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:761)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:76)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.<init>(ActionBarActivity.java:55)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:11)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>(Methods.java:6)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.TestActivity.<init>(TestActivity.java:13)
07-29 10:42:37.962: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.mfg.test.Methods.<init>
```

It seems there is a problem with "Methods method = new Methods();" line in TestActivity class. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: post what errors you are getting? and post log cat..

Comment: I think you have to use Fragment Activity for your requirement.

Comment: @MFG which method(s) of class 1 do you wish to access in class2?

Comment: Hello. I moved Buttons into the onCreate and ran the app again to have its log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what are you trying to do, but that seems like a really bad arhitecture. StackOverflowException happened because your program became infinitely recursive with those two classes. Do you really need Methods Activity?

```
greenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View greenButton) {
            greenButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    });
```

View parameter in that listener is greenButton itself so you can use it and set the background color.

**Explanation**

You dont need Activity for that, you can make normal class like:

```
public class Methods{

public void greenBackground(View rl) {
    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}

public void whiteBackground(View rl) {
    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

}

Make an instance in your activity and use it like that without unnecessary references.

Comment: I wanted to separate the methods from the main activity and call them when I needed. But the progress didn't finish as I expected.

Comment: I added you an explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I moved my "View rl" definition to main class as "final View rl" and used your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Get Id's in onCreate method after `setContentView(R.layout.program);` like:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.program);

    Button greenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GreenButton);
    Button whiteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WhiteButton);

    more code goes here..
```

**And don't forget to mention your Methods activity in Android manifest file**:

Like `<activity android:name=".Methods" />`